# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported curveId: 29

Tags: java, web-services, security, ssl, https

I got this error when try to run my local program inside eclipse.

I am using JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 7. I cant figure out why this error "Unsupported curveId: 29". is been prompted when my apps try to connect to the database, did tested on different laptop with the same setting doesnt have an issue.

```
May 19, 2017 11:49:25 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
INFO: java.security path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security
Security providers: [SUN version 1.6, SunRsaSign version 1.5, SunJSSE version 1.6, SunJCE version 1.6, SunJGSS version 1.0, SunSASL version 1.5, XMLDSig version 1.0, SunPCSC version 1.6, BC version 1.55]
SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
SSLContext provider services:
[SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
, SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.3.14.3.2.29]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSASignature
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
  aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSL -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSLv3 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
]
java.ext.dirs: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unsupported curveId: 29".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1352)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1533)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at my.com.fsd.common.database.DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:65)
    at my.com.fsd.common.utils.ErrorPageInfo.<init>(ErrorPageInfo.java:43)
    at sValidateUser.doPost(sValidateUser.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported curveId: 29
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1483)
    ... 28 more
May 19, 2017 11:49:26 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
INFO: java.security path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security
Security providers: [SUN version 1.6, SunRsaSign version 1.5, SunJSSE version 1.6, SunJCE version 1.6, SunJGSS version 1.0, SunSASL version 1.5, XMLDSig version 1.0, SunPCSC version 1.6, BC version 1.55]
SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
SSLContext provider services:
[SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
, SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.3.14.3.2.29]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSASignature
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
  aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSL -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSLv3 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
]
java.ext.dirs: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Unsupported curveId: 29".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1352)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1533)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at my.com.fsd.common.database.DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:65)
    at sValidateUser.doPost(sValidateUser.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported curveId: 29
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1483)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: See [JDK-8178429 SSLHandshakeException "Unsupported curveId: 29"](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178429). Seems to be caused by upgrade on Windows server where SQL Server runs.

Comment: Try upgrading your JDK version to latest one , the answer at the link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/41e36af0-5ff7-4485-ad66-279defbeae5d/team-explorer-everywhere?forum=TFService suggests that after upgrading the JDK , the issue was resolved for OP.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I can't upgrade the JDK right now..

Comment: last option is im using the bounty castle patch.

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution
https://github.com/tobszarny/ssl-provider-jvm16/releases
It let me stay with Java6 and still connect to SQLServer over SSL.

Comment: i am getting same error on charles proxy! could you tell me how to fix it ?Thanks

Comment: How did you use it?

Comment: @OlivierFaucheux please see the [Wiki](https://github.com/tobszarny/ssl-provider-jvm16). There is not much else to be done, but the described steps. Consider upgrading/using Bouncy Castle provider for recommended problem solution